# Match Facebook pixel pageviews with Offline Event set?

Tags: facebook

I would like to use offline conversion data to build a custom audience that I can match against visitors to my site.
I am currently trying to do this by:

1. Using the Facebook pixel (fbevents.js) to track users, passing `extern_id` with our unique user ID during the `init` call and then tracking pageviews like so:

   ```
   fbq('init', '1234567890', {extern_id: UNIQUE_USER_ID});
   fbq('track', 'PageView');
   ```
2. Later uploading offline event data with the associated `extern_id` of people that have made purchases

But Facebook is giving me a 0% record match rate for the offline event set (I have ~150,000 pageviews and a couple thousand purchases, if that matters). Has anybody succeeded in matching only on `extern_id`, or does Facebook require more user data?

Comment: Hi @Nathron, have you fond a way to achieve this?

Comment: @VatsalPadhiyar nope. Only took a quick stab at it. Sorry :|

Answer (score 5):

I spent hours on this and from what I can gather, the offline events only work in conjunction with Facebook ads. So, your uploaded data is matched only against ads in your account and not the Facebook pixel.

Comment: I don't understand your response. "the offline events only work in conjunction with Facebook ads" How can i pass the extern_id whithout the Pixel ?

Comment: So basically if someone clicks an ad, and I set extern_id and then later report a purchase it should be attributed correctly? from my testing its not working either.

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing `external_id` instead of `extern_id` in the fbq `init` event.

```js
fbq('init', '1234567890', {extern_id: UNIQUE_USER_ID}); // Incorrect
fbq('init', '1234567890', {external_id: UNIQUE_USER_ID}); // Correct
```

You can check the doc here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/advanced/advanced-matching

Comment: Links are great, but it would be even more helpful if you could summarize a possible way to correct the problem outlined in the question.

Comment: Umm... I did summarize the solution in one sentence. Just edited to add a code block to make the solution even more clear.

Comment: @diccccn Is this answer up to date? Neither extern_id nor external_id are mentioned on the page, which you linked.